# sourcetree keeps crashing after upgrade to 4.1.1

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, macos-big-sur

I upgraded the source to latest version 4.1.1 but it keeps crashing whenever I click any repo after that. How can I fix it?

```
Process:               Sourcetree [9208]
Path:                  /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/MacOS/Sourcetree
Identifier:            com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS
Version:               4.1.1 (237)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Sourcetree [9208]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-06-16 12:30:58.563 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D1F6D388-FE59-1547-31C8-BEF723D91654


Time Awake Since Boot: 230000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [9208]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                      10bc16000-10bf0e000    [ 3040K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/MacOS/Sourcetree

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(localOutlineDoubleClick:) from sender STRepoBrowserBookmarkOutlineView 0x7fa54d044600
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I downgrade the source tree version to 3.2.1 and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgrade the source tree version to 3.2.1 and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Same issue on an Intel Mac here.

I manually replaced the executable by the latest one from this [page](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download-archives) (4.1.9) and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Source tree was also crashing on every action. It happened after Mac OS upgrade.
To resolve the issue, i have downloaded the latest source tree and replaced it in my Mac applications.